# Vim slow down in python mode after I type "=" (equal) or " "(while space).

Tags: vim, autocomplete, completion

It seems to happen after I installed YCM.  I also have Python-mode plugin installed because I like the lint and "run inside vim" feature, but I turned off "rope".  My YCM settings are like below.

```
31 " Use gcc syntastic checker
30 let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 0
29
28 " Skip checking of ycm config file at vim startup
27 let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf=0
26
25 " Includes tags in completion
24 let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files=1
23
22 " Include text in comments and strings
21 let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_comments_and_strings = 0
20
19 " Start completion from second char
18 let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion=2
17
16 " Disable chache, rebuild every time
15 let g:ycm_cache_omnifunc=1
14
13 " Enable syntax based completion
12 let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax=1
11
10 " Enable completion while in comments
9 let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 1
8
7 " Enable completion while in strings
6 let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1
```

I tried to profile vim, but I don't get a clue from the result.  Below is my profiling report.

```
    0 FUNCTIONS SORTED ON SELF TIME
    1 count  total (s)   self (s)  function
    2    60   0.883352   0.782989  <SNR>93_GetCompletions()
    3  2967   0.905869   0.579009  pymode#folding#expr()
    4  1997              0.275032  <SNR>110_BlockStart()
    5   302              0.168611  <SNR>93_Pyeval()
    6   120   0.968933   0.066387  youcompleteme#Complete()
    7  1997              0.051828  <SNR>110_BlockEnd()
    8    76   0.030649   0.028957  <SNR>97_GetNearbyTag()
    9   154              0.026513  <SNR>69_Highlight_Matching_Pair()
   10    61              0.025747  <SNR>93_InsideCommentOrString()
   11    61   0.057955   0.016587  <SNR>93_IdentifierFinishedOperations()
   12     6   0.013762   0.013707  <SNR>93_OnFileReadyToParse()
   13    60              0.012566  <SNR>93_OnCompleteDone()
   14     4              0.011961  <SNR>143_SearchParensPair()
   15    74   0.040687   0.010170  Powerline#Functions#fugitive#GetBranch()
   16    76   0.114571   0.009806  <SNR>93_OnCursorMovedInsertMode()
   17     2   0.006829   0.006792  SyntasticRefreshCursor()
   18    61   0.040498   0.005477  <SNR>93_InvokeCompletion()
   19    74              0.005211  308()
   20    91              0.004580  Pl#Statusline()
   21    74   0.005954   0.004241  <SNR>59_buffer_spec()
```

Answer (score 1):

Vim doesn't stand asynchronous job control and is basically mono-thread, so he can only do one thing after the other.
You can't type text while YCM is working.

You should try NeoVim who stand it, it won't solve your problem but will minimize it.